# How can I get grouped value by weight without subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with fields:

`id
category_id
property_id
Weight`

How can I get list with {category_id, property_id} where property_id from the highest weight?

Example:

```
id | category_id | property_id | weight |
 1 |           1 |           1 |     20 |
 2 |           1 |           2 |     10 |
 3 |           2 |           2 |     30 |
 4 |           2 |           3 |     40 |
```

Right results after query:

```
category_id | property_id
          1 |           1 (because 20 > 10)
          2 |           3 (because 40 > 30)
```

It is simple issue, but I am searching easiest and right way, how I can do it with postgresql instruments without subqueries and temporary tables.

Comment: go with `group-by` its a easiest and right way.. I think..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (category_id) t.*
from tablewithfields t
order by category_id, weight desc;
```

EDIT:

You can do this with window functions, but the above is probably more efficient:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by category_id order by weight desc) as seqnum
      from tablewithfields t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This syntax is much simpler than `over () partition by...`, and for some reason this is the first time I've ever seen it. Pretty cool.

Comment: @ngreen . . . This is Postgres-specific syntax that proves to be quite handy, if you are using that database.

Comment: Good choice, but can I see resolve with windows-functions?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes, the syntax is very handy. The SQL syntax is painful and I always have a hard time mapping my mental model of things when using it.